# Why is this alert not closing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The alert inside the body is not closing, I tried to look for a fix but couldn't solve it. Does anyone see anything wrong here? This is just a practice but still would like to know.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-12">
            <p> lorem</p>


            <p class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<!--Content End-->
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `a` tag with a `button` tag.

The [official bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing) indicates that the clickable element should have a `button` tag.